# Angular 7, Protractor and Jasmine HTTP Requests

Tags: angular, http, jasmine, protractor, e2e-testing

I have a simple E2E test case where I check to see if a `h1` tag is present on the page. I am using protractor with jasmine.

My problem is that when I load the page, I have a resolver on the page. The resolver makes a GET request for some data and passes it over to the component. When I run the test, the call is never made successfully (works fine outside of the test environment). It always times out.

Why is this happening? I'm not sure how to proceed.

Here's my code:

**ContentResolver**:

```
@Injectable()
export class ContentResolver implements Resolve<any> {

    resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Promise<any> {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            this.httpClient.get('test/content-data').subscribe(response => {
                if (response.body && response.status < 300) {
                    resolve(response);
                }
                else {
                    reject(response);
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

**Test files**:

```
import { AppPage } from './app.po';

describe('App', () => {
    let component: AppPage;

    beforeEach(async () => {
        component = new AppPage();
        await component.navigateTo('Test');
        await component.successfulNavigation();
    });

    it('should display welcome message', async () => {
        await component.getTitleText().then(response => {
            expect(response).toEqual('Test Data');
        });
    });
});
```

**app.po.ts**

```
import { browser, by, element, ExpectedConditions as EC } from 'protractor';

export class AppPage {
    async navigateTo(path) {
        await browser.get(`http://localhost:8080/${path}`);
    }

    async successfulNavigation() {
        return await browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(element(by.tagName('h1'))), 30000);
    }

    getTitleText() {
        return element(by.tagName('h1')).getText();
    }
}
```

Comment: Your issue not related to protractor

Comment: What error are you receiving?

Comment: I'm getting a 404 if I look in the protractor console. If I type in the endpoint directly in the browser, I get a status of 200 back with the data I'm expecting. If I can't call the endpoint from the test environment for whatever reason, can I at least intercept the call in the test code and return fake data so the tests can keep running?